# How convert a JSON format to another using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, oracle-jet

Iam implementing datepicker using Oracle JET.The JET cookbook provides me sample Datapicker that has JSON file as below.

```
 "Holidays": {
  "*": {
     "1": {
        "14": {
           "className": "holiday"

        },
        "26": {
           "className": "holiday"

        }
     }
   }
```

And Json file I get from my rest services is as below

```
 [
 {
     "YEAR":"2017",
     "MONTH":"1",
     "DAY":[
     {
         "N_DAYS":"25",
         "className":"holiday"
     },
     {
         "N_DAYS":"25",
         "className":"holiday"
     }
 ]

      },
  ];
```

How I can convert JSON file I get from the rest services like above one provided in JET cookbook

Comment: What have you tried? May you add a [mcve] to the question?

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: I tired.but it didn't work out. Simple format it worked well

Comment: JSON.parse, two nested loops building the new structure, JSON.stringify. However it is a bit silly to re-stringify the object just to have the datepicker parse it again. A sample datepicker is a **sample**, probably it can be warped around your own date representation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
myStuff = [
  {
     "YEAR":"2017",
     "MONTH":"1",
     "DAY":[
       {
           "N_DAYS":"14",
           "className":"holiday"
       },
       {
           "N_DAYS":"26",
           "className":"holiday"
       }
    ]
  },
];

Holidays = {
  '*': { }
}

for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
  var month = myStuff[i].MONTH;
  for (var j = 0; j < myStuff[i].DAY.length; j++) {
    if (typeof Holidays['*'][myStuff[i].MONTH] == 'undefined') {
      Holidays['*'][month] = {};
    }
    
    Holidays['*'][myStuff[i].MONTH][myStuff[i].DAY[j].N_DAYS] = {
      className: myStuff[i].DAY[j].className
    }
  }
}

Holidays = { Holidays: Holidays }
console.log(Holidays);
```

Comment: Just a gut feeling, but I think that '\*' is where the YEAR field would get used. (And when it is '\*', it means 'all years')

Comment: Im a simple man. I see the output example I do just likeit)))

Comment: thank you so much!!!! ,it worked well and thank you for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

And Here is the fiddle link
https://fiddle.jshell.net/q80212b7/1/

```js
   var myStuff= [ {
    "YYYY_YEAR" : "2013",
    "MMM_MONTH" : "06",
    "DAY_OUT" : {
      "DAY_OUT_ITEM" : {
        "N_DAYS" : "06",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "Lalat Al Miraj"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "YYYY_YEAR" : "2017",
    "MMM_MONTH" : "06",
    "DAY_OUT" : {
      "DAY_OUT_ITEM" : [ {
        "N_DAYS" : "06",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "Lalat Al Miraj"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "YYYY_YEAR" : "2013",
    "MMM_MONTH" : "01",
    "DAY_OUT" : {
      "DAY_OUT_ITEM" : [ {
        "N_DAYS" : "01",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "New Year's Day"
      }, {
        "N_DAYS" : "24",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "Milad Un Nabi"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "YYYY_YEAR" : "2017",
    "MMM_MONTH" : "01",
    "DAY_OUT" : {
      "DAY_OUT_ITEM" : [ {
        "N_DAYS" : "01",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "New Year's Day"
      }, {
        "N_DAYS" : "24",
        "CLASSNAME" : "Holiday",
        "TOOLTIP" : "Milad Un Nabi"
      } ]
    }
  }];

   

Holidays = {
   'value': { }
}


 for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
  var year = parseInt(myStuff[i].YYYY_YEAR,10);

 
 var month = parseInt(myStuff[i].MMM_MONTH,10);
  
  
 if (typeof Holidays['value'][myStuff[i].YYYY_YEAR] == 'undefined') {
  Holidays['value'][year] = {};
}
  if (typeof Holidays['value'][year][myStuff[i].MMM_MONTH] == 'undefined') {
  Holidays['value'][year][month] = {};

}
 if(myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM instanceof Array) {

 for (var j = 0; j < myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM.length; j++) {
 
  var day=parseInt(myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM[j].N_DAYS,10);
 Holidays['value'][year][month][day] = {
  className: myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM[j].CLASSNAME,
   tooltip: myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM[j].TOOLTIP
  };
  }
  }
  else
   {
 
  var day=parseInt(myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM.N_DAYS,10);
 Holidays['value'][year][month][day] = {
  className: myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM.CLASSNAME,
   tooltip: myStuff[i].DAY_OUT.DAY_OUT_ITEM.TOOLTIP
   };

  }
}



 Holidays = { Holidays: Holidays }
 console.log(JSON.stringify(Holidays.Holidays));
```